# list only directory if contain a specific file name in bash

Tags: linux, bash, ls

Hel lo everyone, I need help with bash commands.

Here is the deal :

I have several directories :

such as

```
path1/A/path2/
 file1
 file2
path1/B/path2/
 file1
path1/C/path2/
 file1
 file2
path1/D/path2/
 file1
 file2
```

and a `/path_to_this_file/file.txt` :

```
A
B
C
D
```

that I use such as :

```
cat /path_to_this_file/file.txt | while read line; do ls path1/$line/path2/
```

then I can list all content in the paths BUT I would like to do a ls only for the `path2` that does not have a `file2` into their directory..

Here only the `path1/B/path2/` should be listed

Does someone have a code for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added an if statement to your code:

```
cat /path_to_this_file/file.txt |
    while read line
    do
        if [ ! -f "path1/$line/path2/file2" ]; then
            ls path1/$line/path2/
        fi
    done
```

Alternatively:

```
xargs -I {} bash -c "[ ! -f "path1/{}/path2/file2" ] && ls path1/{}/path2" < /path_to_this_file/file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job

```
while read line; do
    ls "path1/$line/path2/file2" &> /dev/null || ls "path1/$line/path2"
done < /path_to_this_file/file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `mapfile` aka `readarray` `bash4+` only and a `for loop`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mapfile -t var < path_to_this_file/file.txt

for i in "${var[@]}"; do
  if [[ ! -e path1/$i/path2/file2 ]]; then
    ls "path1/$i/path2/"
  fi
done
```

The `ls` in the above code

```
 ls "path1/$i/path2/"
```

Output is

```
file1
```

If the you want to print just the PATH change the `ls "path1/$i/path2/"` to

```
echo "path1/$i/path2/"
```

Output is

```
path1/B/path2/
```

If you want to print both PATH and file use

```
echo "path1/$i/path2/"*
```

Output is

```
path1/B/path2/file1
```